# Movie where an adventurer and trickster go into a foggy tunnel to find treasure, traps tempt them off the path

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a fantasy movie I watched in reruns in the '70s where an adventurer and his trickster friend had to (near the end of the movie) get through a cave to get a critical/magical treasure.  Inside the cave was lots of fog, and lots of traps to tempt the travelers to stray off the path where, I think, they would be turned to stone.  I remember one of the traps was the illusion of someone being crushed by an enormous snake.

The adventurer was tempted off the path by someone who looked like they were in trouble.  But the trickster friend wasn't tempted.  In fact, when mysterious voices insulted the purity of his mom he shouted back "true too!".

Comment: No need to worry, story identification (regardless if movie, tv series, radio show, novel, short story or comic) is perfectly on-topic here. I vaguely remember having seen a scene like that in a Xena episode, but neither the gender of the sidekick nor the time frame would fit your description.

Comment: Since the question references reruns in the 70s, I would be inclined to think this may be a Hercules movie or one of the Ator or  similar sword and sandals movies. These heroes usually had a sidekick in those films.

Comment: It did have a Greek/Roman era hero vibe to it.

Comment: Harryhausen claymation special effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Thief of Baghdad" (1978 TV movie)?**

It think it WAS Thief of Baghdad, as mwarren thought, but it was this made-for-TV version. I found the complete movie on YouTube. It was 1970s and starred prolific Indian actor Kabir Bedi as prince Taj and Roddy McDowall as the comic sidekick Hasan. You can see the scene with the 'trickster' character(Hasan), in a fog enshrouded cave filled with traps at 1:11:00. The part where he responds to the insult to his mother by saying "Too true" is at 1:11:05.

Comment: That's awesome, I thought it was Thief of Baghdad, but I couldn't find any proof it was the 61 version.

Comment: @mwarren. I found this because I saw it when I was 9 years old and even though I didn't remember that specific scene, I had a feeling that this was the one. When I scanned through the movie on YouTube, there it was! It looks even cheesier than I remember, but I want to watch it again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be The Thief of Baghdad (1961). It is the search for a Blue Rose jewel that will cure a princess of some curse. I haven't found anything specific about the cave but I'll keep looking and update if I find anything.